# Can not serialise a spatial point in .NET 8 using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net-core, serialization, spatial, system.text.json

I have some code to serialize a spatial point CurrentHabitat.SiteLocation (in a server side Blazor 8 app). This fails. The object CurrentHabitat was generated as part of a reverse-engineered EF model from an MSSQL database & the field SiteLocation started life in the database as (geography,null).

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            Converters =
                {
                new MicrosoftSpatialGeoJsonConverter()
                },
            NumberHandling = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals,
            ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
            MaxDepth=100
        };

string thisLatLong = JsonSerializer.Serialize(CurrentHabitat.SiteLocation,options);
```

The value of CurrentHabitat.SiteLocation shows as

```
{POINT (-3.89695 55.99762)}
    Area: 0
    Boundary: {GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY}
    BoundaryDimension: False
    Centroid: {POINT (-3.89695 55.99762)}
    Coordinate: {(-3.89695, 55.99762)}
    CoordinateSequence: {((-3.89695, 55.99762))}
    Coordinates: {NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate[1]}
    Dimension: P
    Envelope: {POINT (-3.89695 55.99762)}
    EnvelopeInternal: {Env[-3.89695 : -3.89695, 55.99762 : 55.99762]}
    Factory: {GeometryFactory[PM=Floating, SRID=4326, CSFactory=CoordinateArraySequenceFactory, GeometryOverlay:Legacy]}
    GeometryType: "Point"
    InteriorPoint: {POINT (-3.89695 55.99762)}
    IsEmpty: false
    IsGeometryCollection: false
    IsRectangle: false
    IsSimple: true
    IsValid: true
    Length: 0
    M: NaN
    NumGeometries: 1
    NumPoints: 1
    OgcGeometryType: Point
    PointOnSurface: {POINT (-3.89695 55.99762)}
    PrecisionModel: {Floating}
    SRID: 4326
    SortIndex: Point
    UserData: null
    X: -3.89695
    Y: 55.99762
    Z: NaN
```

The serialization fails:
{"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'X called on empty Point')"}

And an associated stack trace shows:

```
at NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point.get_X()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.Serialize(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& rootValue, Object rootValueBoxed)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteString[TValue](TValue& value, JsonTypeInfo`1 jsonTypeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize[TValue](TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at HabitatHub3.Pages.ShowPond.<onSaveClick>d__42.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Blahblah\source\repos\HabitatHub3\HabitatHub3\Pages\ShowPond.razor:line 371
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> What I am doing wrong?

It seems that you are using `MicrosoftSpatialGeoJsonConverter` from [`Microsoft.Azure.Core.Spatial`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Core.Spatial/1.2.0-beta.1), while serializing `Point` from [`NetTopologySuite`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetTopologySuite), either convert it to corresponding type from [`Microsoft.Spatial`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Spatial) or try using JSON converter from the [`NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON4STJ`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON4STJ):

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters =
    {
        new NetTopologySuite.IO.Converters.GeoJsonConverterFactory()
    },
    ...
}
```